# Rescale multiple variables at once in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

While working with multiple variable assignments in python, I find it not **Pythonic** at all when I try to rescale all of them at once. Please share your thoughts. For example, what I want is:

`a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4` (*Original assignment*)

`a,b,c,d=2,4,6,8` (*Goal. i.e., rescale by a factor of 2*)

Suppose now you have 3000 variables. Is it possible to achieve the same goal in one line as charm as python has always been doing?

Thanks!

---

Update: Working with dictionaries or using NumPy array could be the solution as the comments or other posts suggested. But that is not what I am looking for. I am a heavy `Mathematica` user, where you can do this as easy as

`{a,b,c,d}={1,2,3,4}` (Original assignment through a Mathematica list)

`{a,b,c,d}={1,2,3,4}*2` (Goal now achieved.)

Basically, I am looking for a similar solution in Python.

Comment: Use a list or dictionary to store the values instead of individual variables. Having 3000 variables is definitely not pythonic.

Comment: You need some sort of a data structure like a `dict` or a `dataframe` to hold so many variables. Then only you can rescale it easily. Otherwise it's just useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for doesn't exist, since Python isn't as "math-oriented" as Mathematica. But, if you need a solution without  libraries, data structures, nor stuff and in just one line, I propose the following:

```
(a,b,c,d) = tuple(map((2).__mul__, (a,b,c,d)))
```

Anyway, I recommend using NumPy as it is considerably optimized and the solution would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an optimized library like numpy and use matrix/array.

```py
import numpy as np 

a,b,c,d=1,2,3,4
print(a,b,c,d)

# Create array
array = np.array([a,b,c,d])

# Calculate
array = 2*array

# Assign variables again
a,b,c,d = array
print(a,b,c,d)

# Or as a two liner
a,b,c,d=np.array([1,2,3,4])
a,b,c,d=2*np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

A `pandas` series may be what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> data
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
dtype: int64
>>> data *= 2
>>> data
a    2
b    4
c    6
d    8
>>> data['a']
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the naive Pythonic way would be something along:

```py
a, b, c, d = (2 * x for x in (1, 2, 3, 4))
print(a, b, c, d)  # Prints 2,4,6,8
```

You can encapsulate this in a small class, and then the usage is quite neat:

```py
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._args = args

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return (x * other for x in self._args)
   
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return (other * x for x in self._args)
    
a, b, c, d = F(1, 2, 3, 4) * 2
print(a, b, c, d)  # Prints 2,4,6,8
```